# Adding multiple frames in the same tab tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Complete Tkinter beginner here. I’m trying to create a GUI where I have multiple frames within a tab, and I can change which frame is being displayed with radio buttons (the radio buttons are inside the tab). This is my current code, which correctly creates the tabs and radio buttons.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("JPM")

#GUI tabs
nb = ttk.Notebook(root)
nb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, padx=10, pady=10)

#GUI tab1 (open orders)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(tab1, text="Open orders")

#GUI tab2 (closed orders)
tab2 = ttk.Frame(nb)
nb.add(tab2, text="Closed orders")


Label(tab1, text="Order#", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab1, text="Order Date", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab1, text="Items", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab1, text="Status", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab2, text="Time Elapsed", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab2, text="Time Left", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab2, text="Unit Price", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Label(tab2, text="Total price", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

u = StringVar()
u.set("all fulfilled")  # Default value of the radio button


Radiobutton(tab1, text="In Collection", variable=u, value="in collection", command=None).grid(
    row=0, column=4, padx=0, pady=5, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(tab1, text="In Production", variable=u, value="in production", command=None).grid(
    row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(tab1, text="In Packaging", variable=u, value="in packaging", command=None).grid(row=0,
column=6, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)
Radiobutton(tab1, text="All", variable=u, value="all fulfilled", command=None).grid(row=0, column=7, padx=10, pady=5, sticky=W)

   
root.mainloop()
```

I tried creating a new frame with tab1 as the parent like this:

```
new_frame = ttk.Frame(tab1)
```

but when I add labels and buttons inside `new_frame`, nothing shows up in `tab1`. My idea was to create a different frame for each radio button, and change the radio button command to:

```
new_frame.tkraise()
```

to raise the correct frame to the top when the radio button is selected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to `grid` your `new_frame`.

Comment: I just tried that, now my widgets are getting displayed but not inside of tab1.

Comment: I think you didn't get the rows and columns correctly. How did you `grid` your frame?

Comment: @Makaveli313: ***"create a GUI where I have multiple frames within a tab"***: This is what `Notebook` is proposed for. Rethink your approach, use `Notebook` **in** `Notebook` instead.

Comment: @HenryYik this is how I grid my frame: 
new_frame = Frame(tab1).grid(row=0, column=0, padx=0, pady=0, sticky=W)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


# Main class.
class Main_GUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.title("JPM")

        #GUI tabs
        self.nb = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.nb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10, pady=10)

        #GUI tab1 (open orders)
        self.tab1 = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab1, text="Open orders")

        #GUI tab2 (closed orders)
        self.tab2 = tk.Frame(self.nb)
        self.nb.add(self.tab2, text="Closed orders")


        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Order#", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Order Date", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Items", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Status", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Time Elapsed", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Time Left", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Unit Price", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")
        tk.Label(self.tab1, text="Total price", font='Helvetica 10 bold').grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")

        u = tk.StringVar()
        u.set("All fulfilled")  # Default value of the radio button


        tk.Radiobutton(self.tab1, text="In Collection", variable=u, value="In collection", command=lambda: self.show_frame("PageOne")).grid(
            row=0, column=4, padx=0, pady=5, sticky="w")
        tk.Radiobutton(self.tab1, text="In Production", variable=u, value="In production", command=lambda: self.show_frame("PageTwo")).grid(
            row=0, column=5, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
        tk.Radiobutton(self.tab1, text="In Packaging", variable=u, value="In packaging", command=lambda: self.show_frame("PageThree")).grid(
            row=0, column=6, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="w")
        tk.Radiobutton(self.tab1, text="All", variable=u, value="All fulfilled", command=lambda: self.show_frame("PageFour")).grid(
            row=0, column=7, padx=10, pady=5, sticky="W")




        container = tk.Frame(self.tab2)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree, PageFour):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("PageOne")


    def show_frame(self, page_name):
                '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
                frame = self.frames[page_name]
                frame.tkraise()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In collection...")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)



class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In production...")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)


class PageThree(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="In packaging...")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)

class PageFour(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="All fulfilled!")
        label.grid(row=0, column=0)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Main_GUI()
    app.mainloop()
```